# React Router CSSTransition

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

It is kind of hard to understand the CSSTransition.

```
<Container className="relative">
    <TransitionGroup className="transition-group">
        <CSSTransition key={currentKey} timeout={timeout} classNames="fade" appear>
            <Switch location={location}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Switch>
        </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
</Container>
```

I still do not understand about:

1. What does `key` in `<CSSTransition />` do? How is this affecting the changes?
2. What does the `location` inside '` do?

Comment: A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements. So it doesn't do anything for the transition itself. `location` also has nothing to do with css transition as it is a react router related prop.

Comment: But if I remove the key, the css transition will not work, also the key is not for defining a list of element in my case. So switch will match the url and route components, then update the DOM? If I remove the location prop again the css transition acts weirdly, as if the transition only done a half of the animation. I am very confused here about how they work.